# what does in logic view of database R, C abrreviations mean?

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

RC mean on delete restrict on update cascade,
but what does the R and C mean?
does R mean that on delete and on update are restrict?

Comment: Um, what? What do you mean by "logic view"? Where do these abbreviations appear? Are you using some kind of database visualization or entity-modelling tool?

Comment: I am not using any kind of tool like u mention here. I just simply have the logical design of database(according to it iam trying to create database),the one where u can see kinds of relations between tables and also there are specified the deletion and updating rules, using the letters like R,C, RC

Comment: So ... You are asking about some kind of diagram someone else has done? Can you show it - add part as an image in your questiin?

Comment: sorry, i wanted to add picture,but i do not have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: Well - without a clear description or an image it will be awfully hard to help you. Especially if it is just some random diagram someone drew. I suspect your guesses are right but that's all I could do too - guess.

Comment: okay, thank you still for trying to help.